# Select a sentence and the context. MySql or php

Tags: php, mysql

I could find a string in a MySql database. Now I want to show also some words before and after to give context. What is the best way to do it.?

In this example textTot is a long blog post. TextPetit is a word or a sentence that this code finds. I could show it echo $textPetit;

Now what I ask is: how to show some words before and some words after $textPetit?

```
$textPetit = "brand is";
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blog
                             WHERE text_post LIKE '%$textPetit%';
                            ")
or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
    $textTot = $row['text_post'];

}
```

Comment: `echo 'hi'; echo $textot; echo 'mom';`

Comment: Or concatenate it: echo 'Text before' . $textTot . ' text after';

Comment: Try [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/) as an search / autocomplete engine

Answer (score -1):

do something like this if you want to add words on query

```
$prefixWords = 'Before ';
$suffixWords = ' End'; 
$textPetit = $prefixWords. 'brand is' . $suffix;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blog
                             WHERE text_post LIKE '%$textPetit%';
                            ")
or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
    $textTot = $row['text_post'];

}
```

Comment: When someone makes a search, he does not know what are the words before and the words after